# How to find singular plural and different wording cases in SOLR

Tags: solr

I'm new to SOLR, but I want to find out how to perform a singular, plural and different wording search in SOLR. Example what I have in my mind.

e.g. this is my data set in SOLR:

```
[
 { url: '/my-awesome-url/' },
 { url: '/my-awesome-urls/' },
 { url: '/my-url-awesome/' },
 { url: '/url-awesome-my/' },
 { url: '/hi/' },
 { url: '/foo-bar'}
]
```

This is my search term `my awesome url`. Is it possible to write a query that would find:

```
[
  { url: '/my-awesome-url/' },
  { url: '/my-awesome-urls/' },
  { url: '/my-url-awesome/' },
  { url: '/url-awesome-my/' }
]
```

If it's possible how to do this? What do I need to know to be able to write this type of query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible. You can apply the fieldtype to your field url.

The fieldtype will consist of `tokenizers` and `filters`.

`Tokenisers` : The job of a tokenizer is to break up a stream of text into tokens, where each token is (usually) a sub-sequence of the characters in the text.  Tokenizers read from a character stream (a Reader) and produce a sequence of Token objects (a TokenStream).

`Filters` : Unlike tokenizers, a filter’s input is another TokenStream. The job of a filter is usually easier than that of a tokenizer since in most cases a filter looks at each token in the stream sequentially and decides whether to pass it along, replace it or discard it.

In your case you can apply standard tokenizer.
All the [Tokenizers](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/tokenizers.html)

Filters like lowercase filters, stemmer filter etc.
All the [Filters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/filter-descriptions.html)

You can try the below field type for your field.

```
<fieldType name="textUrl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```